# How to use field_to_bigquery(self, field) function for MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow

I am trying to export some data from Mysql to GCS and then load the exported jsons into BigQuery tables, but i am having troubles with some mysql datatypes, such as BIT and DateTime, because in the json result they appear with a format that is not right for BigQuery

I was wondering if there is a way to cast those values in a format that is suitable for bigquery without having to do an extra transformation process.

In the airflow documentation for MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator (https://airflow.apache.org/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/mysql_to_gcs/index.html#airflow.contrib.operators.mysql_to_gcs.MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator) I can see some functions that might help like:

*field_to_bigquery(self, field)* and 
*convert_type(self, value, schema_type)*

But i can't figure out how to implement this in my code.

I have tried something like this:

```
MySQLtoGCS_TransTBComplete = MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator(
        task_id='import,
        mysql_conn_id='mysql_default',
        google_cloud_storage_conn_id='google_cloud_storage_default',
        sql='SELECT * FROM table' 
        bucket='{bucket}',
        filename='file.json',
        dag=dag)

MySQLtoGCS_TransTBComplete.field_to_bigquery("datetime_field")
```

Can anyone help me to achieve what i want?

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You can't use these two functions specifically in your code.

- `field_to_bigquery` will be used if your set `schema_filename` in the operator
- `convert_type` is always used during the task execution (you can see that in the source code in `sql_to_gcs.py`

As per the doc says, it seems that some field types in MySQL are not handled correctly (see here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/contrib/operators/mysql_to_gcs.html#MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator.field_to_bigquery). So you might have to implement your custom operator inheriting  `MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator` class and overriding these two methods.